# Determine the parameters of a particle filter that best fit observations

Tags: expectation-maximization, state-space-models, particle-filter

I am wondering is there any established framework to optimize the parameter $\lambda$ of a particle filter such that $p(O|\lambda)$ is maximized, where $O$ is the observation sequence. For HMM and Kalman filter this can be done via the EM algorithm, which guarantees a local convergence. Is there something similar for particle filter, or is the intractable nature of particle filter prevents it from doing so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414907000841) is a paper that describes how you can carry out maximum likelihood with random likelihood approximations. If you already have code that can return likelihood approximations at each parameter input, coding up the most basic algorithm from that paper is pretty simple.

From the abstract:

> We study the asymptotic performance of approximate maximum likelihood
> estimators for state space models obtained via sequential Monte Carlo
> methods. The state space of the latent Markov chain and the parameter
> space are assumed to be compact. The approximate estimates are
> computed by, firstly, running possibly dependent particle filters on a
> fixed grid in the parameter space, yielding a pointwise approximation
> of the log-likelihood function.

There are some other approaches, but their suitability depends on the specifics of your model.

Edit: here's some R code that estimates a stochastic volatility model using the first method. The approx. log likelihood function `svol_lev$svol_leverage_bswc_approx_LL()` uses my R package [`pfR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pfr/index.html). You'll have to change the first line of code to point to your three [`.cpp` files](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/tree/main/vignettes).

````
library(pfr)

# compile c++ code 
svol_lev <- buildModelFuncs("~/pfr/vignettes/", "svol_leverage", verbose = TRUE)

# create parameter grid
#order: phi, mu, sigma, rho
axisDens <- 10
phis <- seq(.5, .99, length.out = axisDens)
mus <- seq(-1, 1, length.out = axisDens)
sigmas <- seq(.01, 5, length.out = axisDens)
rhos <- seq(-.9, 0, length.out = axisDens)
thetaGrid <- as.matrix(expand.grid(phis, mus, sigmas, rhos))
colnames(thetaGrid) <- c("phi", "mu","sigma","rho")

# get data
SPY <- quantmod::getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign = F)
realData <- zoo::coredata(diff(log(quantmod::Ad(SPY))))
realData <- tail(realData, 100)

# get (approx.) log-likelihood on every point in the parameter grid
approxLLs <- apply(thetaGrid, 1, \(params){
  cat(params, "\n")
  svol_lev$svol_leverage_bswc_approx_LL(realData, params)
}  )

# get MLE
paramEst <- thetaGrid[which.max(approxLLs),]
cat("est. params: ", paramEst, "\n")
```
````